# How to define specific columns to be displayed for Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting data from WebApi with some 10 columns and I am using Angular Material Grid in the Front-End.

```
user: User;
dataSource: UsersDataSource;
displayedColumns = ['UserName', 'RoleName', 'ISShared', 'IsDeleted'];
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;
```

In the HTML, I have defined as below...

```
<ng-template>
<mat-table  class="mat-elevation-z8 data-table" [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="UserName"
matSortDirection="asc">
<ng-container matColumnDef="user.userName">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>user Name</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.userName}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="user.RoleName">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Role Name</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.RoleName}}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"></mat-row>
</ng-container>
</mat-table>
<mat-paginator [length]="user.length" [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 50]"></mat-paginator>
</ng-template>
```

Even after defining the columns like this, I am still getting all the columns in the output. It is not picking up the specific columns defined in the Angular Material Table.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is not recognizing the `mat-table` tags in the `html`. Should I need to import some `Component` in the associated `ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined "ISShared" and "IsDeleted" in displayedColumns array in your ts file. try to remove that and check.
(or)
you can simply filter the columns from the api.